In which scripture is this line found? "Venkatesa samo deva na bhuto na bhavisyat..."
In which scripture is this found?

Venkatesa samo deva na bhuto na bhavisyati
Venkatesa samo deva bramhande nasti kinchana


Here you may find something.
